# Uneven layers- Ender 3

Tags: print-quality, creality-ender-3

I got my ender 3 about a month ago, it was working fine. Tried a new brand, overture, this is when I started experiencing problems. First, I was clogging nozzles left and right, then I went back to hatchbox, and my layers are messed up... 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE! How tight are the belts for your x-axis and y-axis? Is your bed tight to the slide? It looks to me you've got a lot of small layer shifts going on, which would indicate you've got slop in your assembly.

Comment: This looks like under-extrusion, have you cleaned the nozzle in between brands? Does the spool have friction so that it does not unspool freely?

Comment: Every time you use a new filament you should perform a new calibration: extrusion steps, filament diameter, temperature calibration tower, extrusion multiplier (if needed). Have you done it?

Comment: I have cleaned my nozzle (replaced it) cleaned my heatingblock. I have not performed a new calibration yet though. How would i do that?

Comment: What print settings are used? What temperature? It looks like underextrusion from a clogged nottle.

Comment: @Cherndon That is under extrusion due lack of force to feed the filament, also could be a problem of temperature which needs 10 to 15° C more. :D I had a lot of those "curly" layers, even my first hand made 3dprinter has some of those parts yet, that I will change on future.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if this problem is unrelated to your material or printer, and purely a matter of slicer breakage. Have you tried printing gcode files you created before the problem appeared? If you use Cura and upgraded it, you might have hit one of the bugs where it assumes by default you have 2.85 mm filament, even though your printer actually uses 1.75 mm. That will create underextrusion that has the whole printed object coming apart like an unravelling mummy. When I've seen it happen, it looks very similar to your picture.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like in Movement without displaycement in x and y it seems to fit (neck-area).
I also would check your belts. There may be a bit too much friction.
Otherwise have you made some Testprints (calibration cube, boat)?

Especially the base looks bad. But it is not a cylinder or?

If you want, you may show us your 3dModell (rendered)

Comment: The print looks as if it has a lot of under-extruded sections, but indeed the base look odd.

Answer (score 0):

Have you replaced your extruder stepper assembly with a metal one? I had a similar issue after a month of printing on my ender 3 because the plastic part had worn through and was causing drag on the filament.